# Como posso obter o value de uma div com id=x

Tags: javascript, json

Bom, o que pretendo é fazer o seguinte:

Eu tenho a pagina index.html, com javascript pretendo fazer um json que me pegue o value de uma div com id="x" da pagina teste.html.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: O que já tentou fazer e qual resultado? Tens algum código para podermos ajudar?

Comment: Não tenho nada, nem tenho noção como se possa fazer isso com js

Comment: Coloque o trecho HTML então! Você está querendo recuperar um atributo tipo data-value da DIV? É isto?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, Sua Pergunta está um pouco Vaga. Porem Fiz 4 exemplos q podem te ajudar

Segue Abaixo.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    var conteudoDiv1 = $("#div1").text(); // Pegar texto Com Jquery
 alert(conteudoDiv1);
});

$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var conteudoDiv2 = $("#div2").data("value"); // Pegar Atributo Com Jquery
 alert(conteudoDiv2);
});

$("#btn3").click(function () {
    var conteudoDiv3 = document.getElementById("div3").getAttribute('data-value') // Pegar Atributo Sem Jquery
 alert(conteudoDiv3);
});

$("#btn4").click(function () {
    var conteudoDiv4 = document.getElementById("div4").innerText; // Pegar texto Sem Jquery
 alert(conteudoDiv4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="div1"> DIV 1- Valor da DIV </div>
  <div data-value='VALOR DATA VALUE' id ="div2" > DIV 2</div>
  <div data-value='VALOR DATA VALUE SEM JQUERY' id ="div3">DIV 3</div>
  <div id ="div4">DIV 4 - Valor da DIV sem JQUERY </div>
  
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value = "Pegar valor DIV 1"/> 
  <input id="btn2" type="button" value = "Pegar valor DIV 2"/> 
  <input id="btn3" type="button" value = "Pegar valor DIV 3"/> 
  <input id="btn4" type="button" value = "Pegar valor DIV 4"/>
```